# Ускoрение суффикснoгo автoмaтa

Tags: c, дерево, c++, теория-автоматов

Имеется суффиксный автомат. Необходимо найти самую длинную пoдстpoку (oбщyю).

Автомат реализован на основе данной статьи: [Суффиксный автомат](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_automata#27).

(если с суффиксным автоматом не знакомы или статью не смотрели, дальше можно не читать)

Работает быстрее Хорспула. Но при работе с длинными строками скорости всё равно недостаточно.

Может кто-нибудь работал с подобной структурой и знает, как её можно ускорить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что за спец. символы. У вас просто строки или какой - то шаблон?  
Слышал что можно строить автомат на хэшах. В каких то случаях даст прирост производительности.

Comment: @Артём Девятов понял, посыпаю голову пеплом.  
Судя по описанию вполне себе ленивая динамика. Может приведете код, суммарную длину строк и их количество? Суффиксный автомат вещь быстрая, с маленькой скрытой константой в ассимптотике.

Comment: @Артём Девятов, если правильно понял 4-5 секунд выполняется 500000 вызовов в каждом ищется общая подстрока 5 строк. И каждый раз это разные 5 строк по 1000 символов (кстати ascii (байт) или что?). Так?

А распараллелить вызовы на количество ядер (или гипертредов) не пробовали?

Comment: @Артём Девятов что делает State::operator+ ? Суммирует длины путей?

Comment: @Артём Девятов вы решаете реальную задачу, или с какого нибудь тестирующего сервера а-ля ACM? В замер времени входит ввод/вывод или другие действия?

Comment: @Артём Девятов, идея в том, что несколько (по количеству ядер) **независимых** запросов выполняются параллельно.

Например, организуете пул потоков-обработчиков и вызывающая программа кидает запросы в очередь.

Comment: @Артём Девятов, вероятно я действительно не понял, причем здесь 500000 вызовов.

Давайте более конкретно.

--

У Вас есть 5 строк по 1000 символов (байт). Требуется найти самую длинную общую для этих строк последовательность байт. Ваша программа работает 3-5 секунд (на какой машине? N CPU (частота), RAM) в зависимости от данных и Вы хотите решить эту задачу более быстро.

(заметьте, я ничего не говорю об алгоритме)

--

Теперь я правильно понял?

Comment: @avp, есть задание: найти наибольшую общую подстроку. На входе до 10 строк и до 10000 символов каждая. Запускаться и тестироваться программа будет автоматически на проверяющем сервере, данные которого я не знаю...

3-5 секунд - это время "лёгких" входных данных(5х1000). Боюсь представить, что будет на 10х10000.

В суффиксном автомате для каждого нового символа создаётся состояние(вершина), а иногда две. Что бы решить задачу, нужно пройтись по всем (или почти по всем) вершинам. Если на вход придёт 10 строк по 10000 каждая, придётся обойти ~200000 состояний.
Про 500000 забудьте - напутал, видим

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

На досуге почитаю про этот автомат и вообще подумаю.

--

Кстати, а использование суффиксного автомата обязательно? Символ это байт (8 бит)? 

А то, может какой-нибудь другой алгоритм в голову придет.

Comment: @avp, это вам спасибо :)

Нет, можно использовать любой другой алгоритм. Поскольку программу проверяет другая программа, насчёт символов точно сказать не могу. Но ввод идёт через стандартный поток ввода (cin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из известных сейчас данных можно сделать вывод, что асимптотически улучшить ничего нельзя, 500000 тысяч раз выполнять O(5*1000) с маленькой скрытой константой даст таки 4-5 секунд.
Остается попробовать уменьшить эту константу.
1)

```
if (state.next[DELIM_FIRST + i] != 0)
...
for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET; i++)
{
    if (state.next[CHAR_FIRST + i] != 0)
    {
```

так делать не совсем верно в плане быстродействия. map::operator[] вставляет элемент при его отсутствии, а значит появятся пустые переходы, в которых нет необходимости. Нужно что то такое:

```
if (state.next.find(DELIM_FIRST + i) != state.next.end())
```

а тут просто перебор:

```
for (std::map<char, int>::const_iterator i = state.next.begin(); i!= state.next.end(); ++i)
{
    ...
```

Так немного ускорим обработку, убрав заранее ненужные операции.

2) Раз строк для поиска всего 5, state::result можно сделать std::bitset или свою битовую маску на базе char/int.

3) В реализации из оригинальной статьи используется std::map для хранения переходов. Это дает экономию памяти и быстрый перебор, но требует логарифмическое время на нахождение перехода. Переходы эти можно сделать обычным массивом, это даст честную константу на поиске, но придется перебирать отсутствующие переходы при переборе (в старой версии статьи об этом было написано, не знаю почему убрали)

```
struct state {
    int len, link;
    int next[ALPHABET_SIZE];
};
```

На деле в столь маленькой std::map будет больше оверхэда (на поддержание дерева), и она будет работать помедленнее массива. Имеет смысл поменять и посмотреть (Если сделать так, совет #1 будет неверен).
Еще можно поменять на хэш-таблицу.

Не исключены также оптимизации исходящие из структуры входных данных.

---

UPD.
4) Присваивание лучше конечно убрать, вместо оператора суммы для состояния сделать operator | (это семантически вернее отражает действие), внутри битовый OR для маски.

Comment: @Dith, там комментарии закончились, отвечаю здесь:
Задача будет решаться с тестирующего сервера. Если бы время на ввод и вывод учитывалось, то решить остальные задачи было бы просто невозможно, так что вряд ли

Comment: @Артём Девятов сильно ускорилось? Вы ведь релиз с оптимизацией запускаете? (глупый вопрос, ну а вдруг? бывает же) Мне тут пришел в голову алгоритм O(сумма длин строк) - сливать суффиксные деревья ^^.